# Javascript Object Access

Tags: javascript, object

I am using a Comet Push Engine called APE (Ajax Push Engine) and whenever I receive a realtime event I receive it in an javascript object called 'raw'.

So if for example if the raw object contains a 'location' value, I can print 'raw.location' and it will give me the value,

```
alert(raw.location);
```

So I have another object called currentSensor, which contains a value like this (in my example it would contain the string 'location'):

> currentSensor.value

How do I programmatically use the currentSensor.value variable to access the 'raw' object? I have tried this:

```
var subsensor = currentSensor.sensorKey;
```

and then

```
alert(raw.subsensor);
```

But I keep getting undefined because the raw object doesn't contain a key called "subsensor" its actually "location". I hope this makes sense!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
alert(raw[subsensor]);
```

The dot syntax cannot help you when you need to access variable indexes. You need to use the array access method.

Note: The dot access method is just syntactic sugar and is not really needed in any place, but it is useful for code readability.

For your entertainment:

```
"1,2,3"["split"](",")["join"]("|")
```

Comment: Thank you guys! I guess I'll go with this one since it was the quickest :)

Comment: By 'quickest' do you mean 'at the top when you sort with newest first'? :)

Comment: Right, first one listed, but thank you all of your advice was helpful, I upvoted each of them

Answer (score 5):

When using dot-notation, you use a literal property name. If you want to use a string, use square bracket notation.

```
foo.bar === foo['bar'];
```

Strings can be variables.

```
baz = 'bar';
foo.bar === foo[baz];
```

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
console.log(raw[currentSensor.value]);
```